# iOS : bar button doesn't appear

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I have two View Controller. there is two segue from first vc to the second vc.I have implemented (with code) right bar button and back button and title in second vc in the view did load .when I segue with button I can see them but when I segue by view controller(for choosing table view cell (did select)) I don't see them

how should I fix them???

this is in the second view did load

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let img = UIImage(named: "delBtn")
    if let top = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem {
        top.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: img, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(dele))
    self.navigationItem.title = "Add/Edit"
    pickerS.delegate = self
    pickerS.dataSource = self
    getMajor()
    if preStudent != nil {
        receivedData()
    }
}
```

this is segue of first view controller

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let con = controller.fetchedObjects, con.count > 0 {
        let obj = con[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "edit", sender: obj)
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if  segue.identifier == "edit" {
        if let des = segue.destination as? EditVC {
            if let obj = sender as? Student {
                des.preStudent = obj
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code so we can try to help

Comment: For the button click, do you have a segue connection? Do you call `performSegue(withIdentifier: "edit", sender: obj)` when the button is clicked?

Comment: no it segue directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigation bar is inherited from parent view controller. If your parent view controller is embedded in a navigation controller and you push to a child view controller, your child view controller will have the navigation bar automatically, and thus have the navigation bar items. In your storyboard, check to make sure your segue type is set to show & push. If it's set to present modally, you will lose your navigation bar in your child controller.

[image]